# Sending email with telnet connection fails

Tags: email, smtp, telnet

I'm trying to send an email establishing a telnet connection with the smtp server. I succeed to establish the connection with the port 587, the authentication works, I enter the `mail from: <>`, the `rcpt to:<>` and it works.

Finally, when I type the data, enter the dot and type enter, I receive a message saying :

> 550 5.5.0 Service refuse. Service refused, please try later. LPN105_510

I'm trying to understand why it doesn't accept to send my email. I tried by establishing a TLS connection, it didn't work. I'm thinking it might be because of the "domain" I'm giving after the `ehlo` (localhost), but I have read that it was not important. If it was because of my IP address, I would not be allowed to get so far (connection + authentication). My ATM would do exactly the same operation, right ?

I really don't see what it can be. Here is the connection sequence :

```
Connected to smtp.laposte.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 lpn-prd-vrin003 ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo localhost
250-lpn-prd-vrin003
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 26214400
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
mail from: <xxxxxxxxxxxx@laposte.net>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: <xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Test
.
550 5.5.0 Service refuse ,service refused, 
please try later.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a number of reasons why your mail gets rejected. However, the rejection message (`Service refuse ,service refused, please try later.`) is not standard and seems to be added as a restriction by the mail server administrator.

In case of Postfix, this can happen for lots of reasons:

- The sender address cannot send e-mails from this domain.
- The recipient address cannot receive e-mails from this domain.
- Although `localhost` is accepted as a `EHLO` FQDN in the RFC, the server admin could explicitly reject it.
- The message body contains an unwanted string.
- The message was filtered by a milter and determined that (for some reason) it shouldn't be sent.
- ...

The only way to determine the reason is asking the e-mail administrator and ask them why are you getting the message rejected. If you're the administrator, please, post Postfix logs (`/var/log/mail.log`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with `laposte.net`.
Maybe they have a crazy anti-spam software.

The google search of [550 Service refused laposte.net](https://www.google.fr/search?q=550+Service+refused+laposte.net&btnG=Search&num=30&client=firefox-b) returns more than 4000 such discussions,
so the problem is better addressed to their website.

You could of course use another mail furnisher, such as gmail.